# node-dev not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: node.js, node-dev

I am using Windows 8 pro 64-bit PC, @2012 and My node version is v6.9.4
npm and node this command work very well, but node-dev command doesn't work and is not recognize as an internal or external command.

I set the user variable path to:

> c:/Python36;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin;C:\Users\Kousher
>   Alam Pranto\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin;C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs;

and system variable path into:

> C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x86;C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\2.0\bin\x64;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs\;C:\xampp\php;C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin;C:\Program
>   Files\nodejs;

but it still doesn't work, what should I do to solve this?

Comment: my nodejs installation folder is : C:\Program Files\nodejs

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You can [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) first and learn [How to Ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example. That makes it easier for us to help you.

Answer (score 1):

You should first install node-dev from npm repository using below command

```
npm install -g node-dev
```

Once done you should be able to run the command from terminal. For detail look at [node-dev library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-dev#installation).

Answer (score 0):

In the discuss problem , no npm command was run, all command give me the 'not recognize err' I just add the npm path to the system path variable and it does the work.